# how to get full path with os.walk function in python

Tags: python

i am using os.walk to find directories, but it does not show the full path

code:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(subdirs)
```

I assign system/ value to path.

Expected output: 
system/a/a

Output: a

Now i could use `glob.glob`, but that lists symlinks, and i do not want that

Comment: `os.path.join(root, <dir or file name from subdirs/files>)`

Comment: `subdirs` is relative to `root`.  As @hmm commented, you have to join root and the subdir to get the full path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for root, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(path):
    print("I am looking in", root)
    print("These are the subdirectories:")
    for dirname in dirnames:
        print(os.path.join(root, dirname))

    print("These are the filenames:")
    for fname in fnames:
        print(os.path.join(root, fname))
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

Putting it together, you get the following:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in subdirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, dir))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

```
import os
for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root,file))
```

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer; it is much shorter, and more efficient.

Comment: This is incorrect. Both `subdirs` and `files` are contained within `root`. `file` is not contained within `subdir`!

Comment: @AnnZen you're answer works, but the other person answered first